# SharePoint list filter jquery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, jquery, filter

I was able to create a SharePoint list filter as per the steps in this solution. [Page a list via A-Z](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39929/page-a-list-via-a-z)

Now I am trying to highlight the selected letter through CSS (.selected) but not able to achieve it. Tried to add dynamic CSS to selected link `$(this).css("color","blue")`. Didn't help.

I think the problem is the changes are gone as it refreshes the page. All I want to do is highlight the letter which is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The page reloads when you click your link, so you need to put JavaScript on the page which on load:

1. extracts the FilterValue1 query string parameter
2. find the corresponding link
3. applies the css

Step 2 will be a lot easier if you add an id to each link

So if you define your links like this:

```
<a id="linkA" href="?FilterField1=FirstLetter&FilterValue1=A">A</a>
<a id="linkB" href="?FilterField1=FirstLetter&FilterValue1=B">B</a>
<a id="linkC" href="?FilterField1=FirstLetter&FilterValue1=C">C</a>
...
```

Then the code you want to execute is like this:

```
(function() {
    var match = location.search.match(/&FilterValue1=(.)/);
    if (match) {
        var element = document.getElementById("link"+match[1]);
        if (element) {
            element.style.color = "blue";
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you your time. Would you please elaborate on point 2. May be with little piece of code if you can.

Comment: Code added to answer